# Python running a cmd command(ffmpeg) with subprocess and wait for cmd to close before executing some code

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

So im using ffmpeg to resize a video, and this takes a little while so before the code continues i have to wait for the cmd to close. I havent been able to find a solution and i hope someone that actually knows their stuff can teach me a way. im probably just doing something retarded...
Anyway i have tried multiple things like using subprocess.Propen() and then using pope() to see when it doesnt return "None" also tried stuff like subprocess.run() with subprocess.CompletedProcess() but i just cant get it to work could someone please care to explain if there is a way to do this and that im just doing it wrong? :)

Here is an example of what I tried

```
p = subprocess.Popen("start ffmpeg -y -i "+DIR+"/post.mp4 -vf scale="+str(nW)+":"+str(nH)+" "+DIR+"/post_r.mp4", shell=True)
    while p.poll() is None:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("alive")
    else:
        print("cmd exited")
```

Also whenever i put shell=False it just breaks instantly and I get this error:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `subprocess.Popen()` if you simply need the process to run while you wait. Legacy `subprocess.call()` or the modern `subprocess.run()` are designed exactly for this use case.

With `shell=False` you need to split the command line into a list yourself. You can call on `shlex.split()` for convenience, but it's not hard to do yourself.

```
subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', DIR+"/post.mp4",
    '-vf', 'scale=' + str(nW) + ":" + str(nH), DIR+"/post_r.mp4"])
```

The `start` looks like you are on Windows and of course then `start` is a feature of the shell as well; if you don't have a shell, `start` is not available (but also not useful).

Comment: ... much like Windows itself, I'm tempted to add, but I digress. Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188 which is for U*x platforms primarily, but nevertheless provides a lot more detail around these issues for Windows as well.

Comment: I did actually try run() and a combination of some other stuff but i just couldnt figure it out. Anyways works like a charm now thank you very much